# Need help setting up Hexo Blog with NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, nginx-reverse-proxy, hexo

I need help setting up a blog on my droplet. I have successfully deployed the blog using Hexo at **blog.mysite.io** but the problem is that the hexo blog redirects it to **blog.mysite.io/blog/public**. Now, I know why it's happening, its because of the blog config that I set up as:

**_config.yml**

```
# URL
## If your site is put in a subdirectory, set url as 'http://yoursite.com/child' and root as '/child/'
url: http://blog.mysite.io/
root: /blog/public
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title/
```

My blog is in **/www/data/blog**. The reason why I set up the root directory as **/blog/public** is, the css and everything else break if I don't. The blog runs fine but only the HTML part.

Here's the nginx **vhosts.conf** configuration:

```
server {
    server_name blog.mysite.io;

    root /www/data/blog/public;
    index index.html index.htm;

        location /
        {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mysite.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mysite.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Anything other than the setting above results in either breaking the site altogether or mismatched paths.
So, how can I serve my website directly at **blog.mysite.io**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to replace `root: /blog/public` with `root: /` in Hexo config.

Nginx can locate full path to your site's directory with `root /www/data/blog/public;` directive.

You can also add this settings at the end of Nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    # for static content
    root /www/data/blog/public;
    index index.html;

    # custom 403/404 redirect
    error_page 403 404 =404 /404/;
}
```